# Send an id as a request to an api which expects a list of ids

Tags: java, rest

I am supposed to make a call from my `service A` to another `service B` to get the results. The issue is in my `service A` the request would always be based on 1 `PersonId`. But the API from which I am consuming takes a `POST List<PersonId>` and returns a `List<PersonResponse>`. I am not sure how to handle this in my consumer. What can be different ways to implement this ?

I can create a List and add that personId to the list and send the request. So basically for each request my list will contain only 1 personId.

I was wondering is there a better way to implement this ?

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks.

Comment: can the client not handle a List<PersonResponse> and just extract the first and only PersonResponse from the List?

Answer (score 0):

If the API from service B accepts List as its argument, then you have to pass a list which contains only that one person id, but, you can also change the API parameters list to receive one PersonId which I think is more reasonable.

Comment: Well I can't as that endpoint is being used elsewhere as well.

Comment: @newLearner Alright, then i think you should pass the id as a list, although I know It does not satisfy what you wanted, but it is just okay with a little bit more of work in processing the response.